# bashでコマンド実行と値を同列に扱う方法があるか

Tags: ubuntu, bash

## 質問事項

bashで用いる変数の中身が数値でもコマンドの文字列でも同じ記述で値を算出する方法がありますでしょうか？

## 実際の問題

bashで竹内関数を実装しようと試み、以下のように書いてみました。
実行環境はUbuntu 18.04です。

```sh
tarai(){
    if [[ "$1" =~ tarai.* ]]; then
        arg1=`$1`
    else
        arg1=$1
    fi
    if [[ "$2" =~ tarai.* ]]; then
        arg2=`$2`
    else
        arg2=$2
    fi
    if ((arg1 > arg2)); then
        tarai "tarai $(($1-1)) $2 $3" "tarai $(($2-1)) $3 $1" "tarai $(($3-1)) $1 $2"
    else
        echo $((arg2))
    fi
}

tarai $1 $2 $3
```

ここで`tarai`関数内の`$1`と`$2`には普通の整数値と`tarai 10 5 0`のような文字列の両方が入るので上記のif文を入れていますが、なんとかこのif文無しに記述することはできないものでしょうか？
自分の知識レベルとしては業務上ファイル操作等で困らない程度にbashを知っている状態にちょっと算術式を学んだくらいになります。
以上、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

次の方法はいかがでしょうか。

```sh
#!/bin/bash
tarai(){
    eval arg1="$1"
    eval arg2="$2"
    if ((arg1 > arg2)); then
        tarai '"$(tarai $(('"$1"'-1)) '"$2"' '"$3"')"'   '"$(tarai $(('"$2"'-1)) '"$3"' '"$1"')"'   '"$(tarai $(('"$3"'-1)) '"$1"' '"$2"')"'
    else
        echo $((arg2))
    fi
}

tarai $1 $2 $3
```

tarai で始まる式の代入を

```
arg1=`$1`
```

ではなく数値の代入に合わせて

```
arg1=$1
```

の形式にしてみました。
コマンド置換の記述を呼び出し側の実引数に記述して、taraiの中でevalを使って評価しています。

---

なお、質問された方のコードでは以下のケースでエラーになります。

```
tarai 2 1 0
```

```
./tarai.sh: 行 14: tarai 1 1 0-1: 式に構文エラーがあります (エラーのあるトークンは "1 1 0-1")
```

呼び出し側で評価したい引数とtataiの中で評価すべき引数を見直すことによりエラーは解消します。回答のコードは修正済みです。

Comment: `tarai $1 $2 $3` とした場合、`$2 - $3 == 1` の場合に常に発生する様です(例えば `tarai 10 5 4`)。

Comment: evalで代入まで行うことができるのですね！記述がすっきりしていてかなり私の意図に近い形です。
またエラーケースのご指摘もありがとうございます。bashで評価順を気にするとなるとここまでしないといけないのですね。。
簡単に遅延評価ができないかと思っていたのですがそう単純なものではなさそうだということを知れました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 3):

**tarai.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

PATH=

tarai(){
    arg1=$($1 2>/dev/null || printf $1)
    arg2=$($2 2>/dev/null || printf $2)

    if ((arg1 > arg2)); then
        tarai "tarai $(($1-1)) $2 $3" "tarai $(($2-1)) $3 $1" "tarai $(($3-1)) $1 $2"
    else
        echo $((arg2))
    fi
}

tarai $*
```

**実行結果**

```sh
bash$ time ./tarai.sh 10 5 0
10

real    0m0.108s
user    0m0.106s
sys     0m0.015s

bash$ time ./tarai.sh 50 30 0
50

real    0m3.409s
user    0m3.133s
sys     0m0.593s
```

Comment: if文をor演算で置き換えた感じですね。ただ、やはり一回の演算で値を計算する方法は無さそうな感じでしょうか。本音を言えば途中変数のarg1, 2の存在すらなしに記述できないものかと考えています。

Comment: zsh や fish, その他のモダンな機能拡張シェルであればできるかもしれません。最善の回答を待ちましょう。